# C# TimeZoneInfo/DateTimeoffset/DateTime conversion

Tags: c#

First let me set up the senario:

Datetime is always stored in the database in EST. I have a need to convert it to the client timezone or from the client timezone to the server timezone.

The client timezone is known at the time of request. So, after reading/googling it, I don't feel the solution that I came with is adequate or maybe I feel it is bit hackish.

The code is the following:

```
 public static class TimeZoneUtility
  {
    static readonly TimeZoneInfo serverTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

    public static DateTime ConvertToServerDateTime(DateTime clientTime, TimeZoneInfo clientTimeZone)
    {
      clientTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(clientTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
      DateTimeOffset clientDateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(clientTime, clientTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(clientTime));
      DateTimeOffset serverDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(clientDateTimeOffset, serverTimeZone);
      return serverDateTimeOffset.DateTime;
    }

    public static DateTime ConvertToClientDateTime(DateTime serverTime, TimeZoneInfo clientTimeZone)
    {
      DateTimeOffset serverTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(serverTime, serverTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(serverTime));
      DateTimeOffset client = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(serverTimeOffset, clientTimeZone);
      return client.DateTime;
    }
  }
```

I have read the following answer and i modeled the solution after it. ([Having problems with converting my DateTime to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354516/having-problems-with-converting-my-datetime-to-utc))

Does anyone see a problem with the solution below? Please note I had to recreate the clienttime intentionally with `DateTime.SpecifyKind(clientTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)` becasue the kind was Local and It was throwing an exception.

If you see a problem, please explain it and suggest a workaround.

Thanks,

Comment: Does all your code work? If so, you'd have more luck on [codereview.se].

Comment: Yes. It seems to be working and outputting the right values.